# Gravity Form Plugin not Working on Microsoft Edge

Tags: wordpress, microsoft-edge, contact-form, gravity-forms-plugin

Visitors are unable to submit the form using Microsoft Edge. All other browers that I've checked so far are working fine.

When you click 'submit' nothing happens.

Form in question - https://www.vulcansystems.co.uk/contact/

Comment: you have a javascript error in this page. (Uncaught ReferenceError: gformInitSpinner is not defined ). please check google chrome console.

Comment: Thanks, Mehrshad.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test your site with Chrome and Edge browser. Both browser shows many errors in the console. I noticed that form data get submitted in MS Edge by clicking the submit button.

I tested with MS Edge 44 version.

[image]

So as you seen in the test. Data get submitted. Further, you can try to check and solve console errors may help to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I did receive confirmation message from Gravity Forms, assuming you used ABC@XYZmail.com as your email. It must be certain versions of Microsoft Edge. I am using Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: I suggest you to install the latest updates for your Windows OS will update the MS Edge with latest version. Than you can try to make a test with it.